# Single Sign On solution Using Asp .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, authentication, single-sign-on

I'm looking to develop a Single Sign-On (SSO) solution similar to Okta. The basic concept is to allow users to access multiple applications, such as Salesforce and Azure, from a central portal. When users log in to our platform, they should be able to click on icons representing these applications and seamlessly access their respective accounts on Salesforce or Azure. and i have no clue on how i can realize this solution